Oracle group timestamp per 10 seconds
I have a large table partitioned by month, containing billions of rows, structured as follows:
CREATE TABLE EXEC_REC (
    ...
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (M_MIN_DATE)
INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
(PARTITION BEFORE_2010 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-01-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')))
ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT INITRANS 5;

However, I am encountering performance issues, especially when dealing with user queries on the UI
where they can specify criteria like timestamps for exporting results (based on M_MIN_DATE column)

Is there any way to make a materialized view grouping the M_MIN_DATE per 10 seconds ?
And to refresh the data with fast refresh ?

Can I have any gain If I merge partitions on the table ?
For example except from BEFORE_2010 to create also a BEFORE_2020 partition ?


Thanks in advance

We need more information, like a sample query and execution plan. In general, this kind of scenario usually requires (1) successful partition pruning [predicates applied to the partitioning key], (2) full segment scans [no indexes being used], (3) parallel query [hint if necessary], (4) sufficient PGA allocation to do aggregation in memory, (5) hash joins to other tables [rather than nested loops]. Yes, sometimes aggregating at a larger time granularity can be a technique to reduce I/O but before you go to that length (costly in terms of space and code redirection) first focus on SQL tuning.
